# How to fix file creation date

Tags: c#, file

I added a check in my class FileLogger, I want to remove log.txt if the file was created, but the file creation date is always different from today's date..:

[image]

After the code has been completed (File.Delete and File.Create) I get file with 5 October, but today is 7 October

Comment: Was the file created on the same machine?

Comment: @TaW yes, log.txt was created in my PC

Comment: Try to use `FileInfo.LastWriteTime` property instead of `CreationTime` (in meaning, if no writes was performed to log today - it can be deleted). Or, as is often done, add date to log file name: "MyLog_01.01.2021.txt".